# incorrect joystick sensor data when access it using STM32F4 discovery

Tags: c, stm32f4discovery, adc

I want to access joystick sensor data using 10bit ADC2 and ADC3 of stm32f4 discovery by divide the two variable resistor data as X and Y. All I want is when when I pull the analog maximally, the Y ADC data shows 0 and when I push the analog, it shows 1024 value. and for X data uses the same analogy. when I use arduino it did great and the data was good. the middle position of the analog gave me value around 512. But it did not go well when I use stm32f4 discovery. the middle value gave me around 810 and value when i push maximally the data get weird and it shows around 769. both X and Y gave me the same behavior.

```
void ADCinit_SoftTrigger()      //configurations of adc(sensor) reader
{
   GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
   ADC_InitTypeDef  ADC_InitStructure;
   ADC_CommonInitTypeDef ADC_CommonInitStructure;

   RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC2 | RCC_APB2Periph_ADC3, ENABLE);
   RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_3;
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AN;
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;

   GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

   ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_Mode = ADC_DualMode_RegSimult;
   ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_Prescaler = ADC_Prescaler_Div2;
   ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_DMAAccessMode = ADC_DMAAccessMode_Disabled;
   ADC_CommonInit(&ADC_CommonInitStructure); //

   ADC_InitStructure.ADC_Resolution = ADC_Resolution_10b;
   ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
   ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
   ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge_None;
   ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T1_CC1;
   ADC_InitStructure.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
   ADC_InitStructure.ADC_NbrOfConversion = 1;
   ADC_Init(ADC2, &ADC_InitStructure);

   ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC2, ADC_Channel_2, 1, ADC_SampleTime_3Cycles);
   ADC_Init(ADC3, &ADC_InitStructure);
   ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC3, ADC_Channel_3, 1, ADC_SampleTime_3Cycles);

   ADC_Cmd(ADC2, ENABLE);
   ADC_Cmd(ADC3, ENABLE);
}

uint16_t ADC_read(ADC_TypeDef* ADCX,uint8_t channel,uint8_t ADC_SampleTime)
{
   ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADCX,channel,1,ADC_SampleTime); 
   ADC_SoftwareStartConv(ADCX);
   while(ADC_GetFlagStatus(ADCX, ADC_FLAG_EOC)==0);
   return ADC_GetConversionValue(ADCX);
}

void read_sensor()
{
  x=ADC_read(ADC2,ADC_Channel_2,ADC_SampleTime_144Cycles); //pin A2
  y=ADC_read(ADC3,ADC_Channel_3,ADC_SampleTime_144Cycles); //pin A3

  sprintf(bufADC,"\nX : %d     Y : %d",x, y );
  USART_puts(bufADC);
}
```

Comment: What does a connected multimeter show when pushing?

Comment: when pushing from minimal to max, at some 75% of the analog angle it gave me 1023 and after that decreasing to 760 until 100% max angle

Comment: The multimeter gave you 1023 V?

Comment: @koalo _Obviously_ the OP means the ADC read value...

Comment: Stupid question but did you set the STM32F up to use 10 bit reads? Otherwise you should obviously divide by 4096 and not 1024, since the STM32F seems to have a 12 bit ADC.

Comment: @Lundin and obviously I meant the voltage in my clarification comment so that we are able to verify his conversion and rule out any problems with the electronics

Comment: @koalo If the OP measure 1024V on their evaluation board, then it means that the board is completely fried and that they must be programming sitting inside some power station where such exotic voltages are available.

Comment: @koalo there is nothing to do with electronic, the joystick work well when I use it with arduino

Comment: @Lundin I've set the STM32F4 to use 10bit reads in this line: ADC_InitStructure.ADC_Resolution = ADC_Resolution_10b;